# WPF - where can I find some window layout ideas/examples and resource files that will make my application look better

Tags: wpf, file, resources

I enjoy working with WPF but I need a little more of "designer's touch" to my applications. I have been unable to find a good resource for WPF layout examples and color schemes along with the corresponding resource files.Are there any good resources out there to help developers make their applications really "pop".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Microsoft Expression Community Gallery](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/en-us/) provides a community site for sharing WPF and Silverlight resources.

In particular, look under "Themes", "Samples", and "Art / Design" for templates, styles, and other visually appealing things you can use in your applications.

Comment: Very close to what I'm looking for but most stuff seems to be for Silverlight and not WPF.

Comment: Most themes are easily converted from Silverlight to WPF, since the XAML can be left nearly unchanged.  (Going the other way isn't as easy, though, since WPF is mostly a superset of SL...)

Answer (score 4):

[Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511258.aspx) is a good place to start. If you're using a set of proprietary controls (like the [WPF controls from Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf.aspx)), they usually have built in skins/styles that you can change just like flipping a switch. [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/) always has a lot of useful things, I wouldn't be surprised to see some WPF-related styling resources.

Hope that helps a little!

**EDIT**

From Codeplex: [WPF Themes](http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/), [WPF Contrib](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=wpfcontrib&title=Themes&referringTitle=Home)

From Microsoft: [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx)

From Adobe: [Kuler](http://kuler.adobe.com/#create/fromacolor) (for picking colors schemes)

Other: [Reuxables](http://www.nukeation.com/reuxables.aspx) (neat-o theme I just stumbled upon)

Comment: Great list but a few of those were broken links. I was particularly disappointed in the WPF themes link. Exactly what I'm looking for but there are no downloads available on that project.

Comment: Hmm, all those links worked fine for me just now. Odd. Also, the WPF Themes Codeplex page doesn't have anything under the "Downloads" tab, but you can download the source from the "Source Code" tab. You can surely get additional information from the "Discussion" tab.